# Wepshpere: order of loading of modules

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

We have irritating problem while deploying .war (which contains ejb components in jar inside) on two different PCs with same WAS v8.5.2.2

When we deploy our app on the first PC - everything looks good, while deploying on the second - it fails 'cause it is not able to find ejb bean in environment.

It's important to note that servers configs are quite the same.
But order of loading of modules is different though: 
in first case it loads ejb module(jar) first and then web module, in second case - visa versa:

> WebGroup SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module:  UD-BACKGROUND-PROCESSES-SERVER.
>   .....
>
> WSVR0037I: Starting EJB jar: ud-background-processes-server-1.18.0_15914.war

And we think that it's the cause of failure.

How and where can it be configured?

Moreover - couple of times it was possible to make it load in the right order without changing server configuration! But we couldn't catch the rule of such behavior changing.

Also .war (and jars in it) contains neither of Websphere specific config files(like ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml) nor ejb specific files (ejb-jar.xml). It's configured using annotations @Stateless\@EJB\@LocalBean only.

Any thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we've found out the reason of such behavior and we have changed order of loading by turning off checkbox values (see pictures) and restarting the server.

[image]

### -----

[image]

### -----

[image]

Actually we don't know yet which one made sence

Answer (score 1):

If the modules are included in the same application/EAR, then by default, the EJB modules in that application should be started before WARs in that application.

If the modules are in separate applications, then you will need to [configure the application start weight](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/trun_app_startup.html) to ensure the EJB application starts before the WAR application.

Comment: Should be but they aren't, unfortunately. Hmm.. actually we have just .war, not ear, but WAS seems to install it as ear application (it creates folder ud-background-processes-server-1_18_0_15914_war.ear)... so, looks like we need to work with ear with ejb jar and war inside...